# When editing a form in a modal, how do I get the previously selected option from a dependent dropdown?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have two tables, one for customers and one for their vehicles. When submitting the form the vehicle is dependent on which customer you select. Now when I go to edit the form, I can select vehicles by changing the customer like so...

```
$(document).on('change','#customeredit', function(){
        var customer_id = $(this).val();
        if(customer_id){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'get-vehicle-from-customer.php',
                data:{'customer_id':customer_id},
                success:function(result){
                    $('#vehicleedit').html(result);

                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#vehicleedit').html('<option value="">Vehicle</option>');
        }
    });
```

but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get it to automatically show the list of vehicles without changing the customer selection first. I know I'm missing something simple here but I'm new to this and could really use some direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

i would define your ajax call as a function , then u can call it everywhere u want:

```
    var fx_load_customer = function() 
        {
          //var customer_id = $(this).val();
            var customer_id = $('#customeredit').val();
            if(customer_id){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'get-vehicle-from-customer.php',
                    data:{'customer_id':customer_id},
                    success:function(result){
                        $('#vehicleedit').html(result);

                    }
                }); 
            }else{
                $('#vehicleedit').html('<option value="">Vehicle</option>');
            }
        }   

        $(document).on('change','#customeredit', function(){ fx_load_customer(); });
        fx_load_customer();
```

Comment: Okay! I see where you're going with this, sort of. So I've got this so it works on change again like before, I click on a customer, close the modal, reopen it and it shows the right vehicle that was selected on form submit.

Now how do I call this function and still get it to show the right option? I tried 

`$(window).on('shown.bs.modal', function() { 
    $('#modalEdit').modal('show');
 fx_load_customer();
});`

but it just shows the list, doesn't show the option that was selected on form submit.